# Different level of logs in different log files

Tags: log4j2

How can we write a simple log4j2.xml file with different levels of logs going into different files?

For example we have error logs any info logs I need to push all error log messages into one log file and all info log messages into another file.

I want that info message in InfoController.log file and error message in LoginController.log file

How can i do it?

Comment: Why do you use same name for the loggers? Try changing into <logger name="com.mvc.info"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally got the answer by doing this i got the logs in different files.

```
<Loggers>
    <logger name="com.mvc.login" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="LoginController" level="error"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="InfoController" level="info"/>
    </logger>
  </Loggers>
```

Comment: Just to be precise AppenderRef level is a "less or equal condition". If you have an AppenderRef level of INFO all loggings with level less or equal than INFO (info, warn, error, fatal, off) will go to to the given appender.

Answer (score 2):

Loggers must have unique names. The second logger in your config will replace the first one, which explains why you don't see any output for the appender referenced by the first logger.

Normally, a configuration has a root logger that will receive all events. I would recommend that, so that part of the config becomes:

```
<Loggers>
    <logger name="com.mvc.login" level="error" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="LoginController"/>
    </logger>
   <root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="InfoController"/>
    </root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: if i provide different name for loggers how can i get logs of same class? for example the class name is com.mvc.login how can i give different names for loggers?

Comment: i edited the question can you please look into it now?

Answer (score 2):

```
  <Filters>
    <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT" />
  </Filters>
```

This will print only Info log.If you assign level error then it will print only warn message etc.